# In ES6, what is the syntax to specify an array for retrieving some value from a React State?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm using React but I think my problem isn't specific to React.

I'm using a hook from a library (wagmi) and it returns some states. The data state is an array and I'm aliasing it with the dataWhitelist name , and I can access it later in my code, everything's fine :

```js
    const { data: dataWhitelist, isSuccess: isSuccessWhitelist, isError: isErrorWhitelist } = useContractReads({
        contracts: [
            {
            (...)

a = dataWhitelist[0] // ok
b = dataWhitelist[1] // ok
```

I know data.length is 2 and I want to do something like :

```js
// this first line fails
    const { data: [numberOfNft, maxNft], isSuccess: isSuccessWhitelist, isError: isErrorWhitelist } = useContractReads({
        contracts: [
            {
            (...)

a = numberOfNft      // I want to do this
b = maxNft           // I want to do this
```

But it doesn't compile.

[image]

Is it possible to do something like this, and what is the syntax ?

Comment: what is name of the key that is returned? is it `data` or something else.

Comment: It should work like this : https://codesandbox.io/s/es6-playground-forked-u10ioe?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Instead of mentioning the line fails, you should put the exact error for better suggestions and answers

Comment: Please show the error message

Comment: Sry, I've edited the msg with my error. Thanks for your support !

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
const { data, isSuccess: isSuccessWhitelist, isError: isErrorWhitelist } = useContractReads({
        contracts: [
            {
            (...)

// Just Destructure the Array
const [numberOfNft, maxNft] = data;
```

Comment: Yeah thx it works for sure, but It is quite cumbersome... I wanted a more elegant solution, if possible... That's the core of my question :)

Comment: There can't be any more elegant solution because as per the `useContractReads` Documentation. Data is of type `data ?: Result[]` which means it's optional & initially while the hook initializes data could just be `undefined`. So, you actually can't destructure the data in one line. https://wagmi.sh/docs/hooks/useContractReads

Comment: I've searched alternatives but it seems you're right... Ok I'll go with this !

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure an array value using bracket notation:

> Read more at [Destructuring assignment - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
const exampleReturnValue = {data: [1, 2, 3]};

const useExampleReturnValue = () => exampleReturnValue;

const {data: [a, b]} = useExampleReturnValue();

console.log({a, b}); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

And if the `data` property is not always defined, then you can use the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) to supply a fallback array like this:

```js
const exampleReturnValue = {};

const useExampleReturnValue = () => exampleReturnValue;

const {data} = useExampleReturnValue();

const [a, b] = data ?? [];

console.log({a, b}); // { a: undefined, b: undefined }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the less cumbersome solution I've find out so far.

I'm working with next.js, and this hook doesn't return the value server side, for sure.
Optional chaining operator ?. will help me to avoid dealing with the undefined value serverside

```js
    const { data: dataWhitelist, isSuccess: isSuccessWhitelist, isError: isErrorWhitelist } = useContractReads({
        contracts: [
        (...)

    const [numberOfNft, maxNft] = [dataWhitelist?.[0], dataWhitelist?.[1]]
        (...)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setHasMounted(true)
    }, [])
        (...)

return (
        (...)
   {hasMounted && isSuccessWhitelist && <ShowNumberNft numberOfNft={numberOfNft} maxNft={maxNft} />}
        (...)
       )
```